# Вертикальная центровка изображения в блоке

Tags: css, css3, изображения

Здравствуйте.
Есть блок `width:100%;height:300px;overflow:hidden;`
Есть изображение внутри него `position:relative;width:100%;height:auto;`
Соответственно, изображение начинается от верхнего левого угла блока, тянется по ширине на 100%, а внизу обрезается после 300px, из-за `overflow:hidden;`
Задача: сделать так, чтобы изображение центрировалось по вертикали, т.е. в блоке отображалось 300px из центральной части картинки, а верхний и нижний края обрезались.
Кто что может посоветовать? Вариант сделать картинку бэкграундом мне известен, и рассматривается в последнюю очередь.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сначала через `top` помещаете начало картинки на уровень в 50% от высоты родителя, затем через `transform` смещаете картину по оси Y на 50% выше, но уже от размера самой картинки.

```css
.b-pict {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.b-pict > img {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="b-pict">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Для таких целей можно использовать свойство [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit). Поскольку пока что оно не поддерживается повсеместно, нужно сделать фоллбек при помощи `@supports`.

```css
.b-pict {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.b-pict > img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
@supports (object-fit:cover) {
  .b-pict > img {
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}
@supports not (object-fit: cover) {
  .b-pict > img {
    height: auto;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="b-pict">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any" alt="">
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/any">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение без явного указания размеров, которое я использую, когда нужно выровнять блок по вертикали, но его конечная высота неизвестна. Работает даже в IE9. Пример:

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Обертка */
.container-fluid:before {
   content: '';
   height: 100%;
   display: inline-block !important;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Блок, который нужно выровнять */
.row {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Проще всего это сделать через flexbox.

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  
  display: flex;
  /* Центрируем по вертикали */
  align-items: center;
  /* Центрируем по горизонтали */
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если известна высота родительского элемента(как в вашем примере), то просто:

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.row{
  line-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Или так:

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.row{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Вы ответили правильно на заголовок вопроса, но суть вопроса была в другом.