# Как сделать, чтобы высота блока с картинкой сама подстраивалась под экран?

Tags: html, css, изображения

Есть блок с картинкой с заданной фоновой картинкой и минимальной высотой. 
Интересует, как с помощью стилей так, чтобы высота картинки подстраивалась под экран при его увеличении (`min-height` изменялся), т.е. фактически чтобы картинка с цифрами не скрывалась (350Х150) за блоком, а была всегда логически расположена по центру, была на всю ширину и сохраняла пропорции  на любых разрешениях экранов. [Фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/6xzyokuh/)

```css
.background {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/350x150);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 1px;
  min-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background"></div>
```

Ну в каком месте возможный дубликат? вопросы совершенно разные - у меня есть необходимость, чтобы высота блока подстраивалась под экран, т.е. увеличивалась и уменьшалась в зависимости от размеров экрана. К сожалению, пока до сих пор универсального решения не найдено

Comment: Тоесть ви хотите чтоб картинка всегда бида по центру екрана независимо от ево розрешения?

Comment: `background-size: 100% 100%;`

Comment: так или нет? https://jsfiddle.net/6xzyokuh/1/

Comment: @Lieutenant Jim Dangle я хочу при увеличении экрана, чтобы высота картинки тоже увеличивалась, а не оставалась прежней, т.к. на некоторых разрешениях выглядит не очень

Comment: @Elena к сожалению, при этом свойстве картинка начинает сужаться и раз=стягиваться, мне же нужно, чтобы она пропорционально ресайзилась

Comment: Как насчет `background-position: 50% 50%;`?

Comment: @Sasha Omelchenko это вариант, но лишь наполовину, т.к. картинка начинает растягиваться и искажаться - теряется изначальные пропорции. вот, если бы при увеличении экрана - увеличивалась высота картинки, то было бы здорово!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вертикальная центровка изображения в блоке](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623923/%d0%92%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Найдено, решение, которое меня полностью устроило. [Фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/6xzyokuh/9/)

```css
.background {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url(http://mobidevices.ru/images/2017/01/Nintendo-Switch-1.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 66.6666666666%;
  /* H / W * 100% = 66.67 */
}
```

```html
<div class="background"></div>
```

Comment: `padding-bottom: 66.6666666666%;` выглядит отлично...

Comment: @Yuri это сам принцип и это конкретно под эту картинку и с макс точностью. я в большинстве использую стандартные 1920 на 1080, которые делятся на более красивые числа

Answer (score -1):

Примените свойство `background-size: contain;`

```css
.background {
  background: url("https://mobidevices.ru/images/2017/01/Nintendo-Switch-1.jpg") no-repeat 50% / contain;
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="background"></div>
```

Comment: к сожалению, при `background-size: contain;` фон начинает повторяться - это не универсальный способ..

Comment: @Вася а background-repeat: no-repeat добавить - не судьба?

Comment: @Вася написал вам обновленный пример со всеми свойствами.

Comment: спасибо, удалось добиться результата, но он не окончательный, т.к. за счет `height: 800px;` получаются сверху и снизу промежутки без фона

Comment: @Вася высоту сами можете регулировать. 800 - это пример

Comment: ну как - под каждое разрешение и браузер экрана задавать свое? хотелось бы, чтобы высота резинилась, а не на костылях создавать решение

Comment: @Вася необязательно задавать высоту экрана в px. Задайте в vh

Comment: тогда картинка не растягивается на всю ширину и это не кроссбраузерно для ie..

Comment: @Вася тогда примените background: url("https://mobidevices.ru/images/2017/01/Nintendo-Switch-1.jpg") no-repeat 50% / cover;

Comment: вверху написал решение, которое меня полностью устроило. Спасибо за помощь